# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar dos procedimientos del mismo paquete en pl sql? me esta dando error

Tags: oracle, plsql

Estoy creando un proceso que me inserta información en una tabla y después con el mismo id (viene de una secuencia) lo inserto en otra tabla mediante un procedimiento del mismo paquete. pero cuando lo ejecuto con el segundo procedimiento me despliega este mensaje:

> ORA-06550: line 47, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", line 670 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658 ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", line 656 ORA-06512: at "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1768    -

El código es:

```
DECLARE
    p_sid               NUMBER;
    p_set_of_books_id   NUMBER;
    p_period_name       VARCHAR2(6);
    p_num_per           NUMBER;
    p_area_desde        VARCHAR2(10);
    p_area_hasta        VARCHAR2(10);
    p_cuenta_desde      VARCHAR2(30);
    p_cuenta_hasta      VARCHAR2(30);
    p_ubicacion_desde   VARCHAR2(10);
    p_ubicacion_hasta   VARCHAR2(10);
    p_oficina_desde     VARCHAR2(10);
    p_oficina_hasta     VARCHAR2(10);
    p_nivel_ubicacion   NUMBER;
    p_resume_area       VARCHAR2(2);
    p_resume_oficina    VARCHAR2(2);
    p_tipo_proyecto     VARCHAR2(6);
    p_tpo_rep           VARCHAR2(10);
    v_sid               NUMBER;



BEGIN


SELECT GL_XXGL.XXGL_TMP_EDO_RES_S.NEXTVAL INTO v_sid FROM DUAL;


   Xxgl_ESTADO_RESULTADOS_PKG.consulta_edo_result(
p_sid => v_sid,
p_set_of_books_id => 1001, 
p_period_name => 'OCT-20',
p_num_per =>null,
p_area_desde => '',
p_area_hasta => '' ,
p_cuenta_desde => '',
p_cuenta_hasta => '',
p_ubicacion_desde =>'999999',
p_ubicacion_hasta => '999999',
p_oficina_desde => '',
p_oficina_hasta => '',
p_nivel_ubicacion => '',
p_resume_area => 'N',
p_resume_oficina => 'N',
p_tipo_proyecto => '',
p_tpo_rep => NULL
     );
END;


BEGIN 
   Xxgl_ESTADO_RESULTADOS_PKG.R_EDO_RES(
p_sid => v_sid,     
p_resume_area => 'N',
      p_resume_oficina => 'N'
     );
END;



  'agradecere su ayuda.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Un procedimiento es un conjunto de comandos de SQL, por lo que puedes poner varios comandos diferentes dentro del mismo, incluyendo ejecutar otros procedimientos que se encuentren en la base de datos. En el caso de este script no se está utilizando la sintaxis correcta para crear un procedimiento ya que los comandos `begin` y `end` solo deben usarse una sola vez al principio y al final de cada procedimiento respectivamente.

Ejempo de la documentacion de oracle en https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE remove_emp (employee_id NUMBER) AS
   tot_emps NUMBER;
   BEGIN
      DELETE FROM employees
      WHERE employees.employee_id = remove_emp.employee_id;
   tot_emps := tot_emps - 1;
   END;
```

Esta seria la forma correcta de crear el procedimiento que buscas:

```
DECLARE
    p_sid               NUMBER;
    p_set_of_books_id   NUMBER;
    p_period_name       VARCHAR2(6);
    p_num_per           NUMBER;
    p_area_desde        VARCHAR2(10);
    p_area_hasta        VARCHAR2(10);
    p_cuenta_desde      VARCHAR2(30);
    p_cuenta_hasta      VARCHAR2(30);
    p_ubicacion_desde   VARCHAR2(10);
    p_ubicacion_hasta   VARCHAR2(10);
    p_oficina_desde     VARCHAR2(10);
    p_oficina_hasta     VARCHAR2(10);
    p_nivel_ubicacion   NUMBER;
    p_resume_area       VARCHAR2(2);
    p_resume_oficina    VARCHAR2(2);
    p_tipo_proyecto     VARCHAR2(6);
    p_tpo_rep           VARCHAR2(10);
    v_sid               NUMBER;



BEGIN


SELECT GL_XXGL.XXGL_TMP_EDO_RES_S.NEXTVAL INTO v_sid FROM DUAL;


   Xxgl_ESTADO_RESULTADOS_PKG.consulta_edo_result(
p_sid => v_sid,
p_set_of_books_id => 1001, 
p_period_name => 'OCT-20',
p_num_per =>null,
p_area_desde => '',
p_area_hasta => '' ,
p_cuenta_desde => '',
p_cuenta_hasta => '',
p_ubicacion_desde =>'999999',
p_ubicacion_hasta => '999999',
p_oficina_desde => '',
p_oficina_hasta => '',
p_nivel_ubicacion => '',
p_resume_area => 'N',
p_resume_oficina => 'N',
p_tipo_proyecto => '',
p_tpo_rep => NULL
     );

   Xxgl_ESTADO_RESULTADOS_PKG.R_EDO_RES(
p_sid => v_sid,     
p_resume_area => 'N',
      p_resume_oficina => 'N'
     );
END;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Javier ya hice el cambio y se esta ejecutando por el momento todo bien, te comento como termina, saludos

Comment: Javier, las respuestas que solo tienen código tienden a considerarse de baja calidad,  sugiero que incluyas una explicación de por qué o como esto resuelve el problema. Para más información, te invito a leer [answer]. Un saludo.

Comment: @Douglas, si el aporte de Javier resolvió tu problema, está bien si regresas al final a contarle como terminó todo, pero lo que podrías hacer YA es aceptar la respuesta y, si la consideras de buena calidad, dejarle tu voto. Dado que eres nuevo en el sitio, te invito a hacer el [tour] para enterarte de como funciona SO.